# Retrieve an object from Unity IoC container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, spring-mvc, unity-container, ioc-container

When I worked in Spring, I could get a bean a bean listed in my applicationContext. This object would already be populated with all the values that were there when the bean was instantiated. Great.

I can't find a way to do this in Microsoft Unity IoC. We recently introduced this framework into our codebase and nobody is really very familiar with it yet. The only examples I've seen involve resolving the type of the object and then repopulating all the values. Yuck. I don't want to do this.

I want to pull the object from the container and it should be ready to go. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a call to `Resolve` not enough, e.g.

```
var container = // create container.
IService instance = container.Resolve<IService>();
```

Unity will inject any dependencies before returning the resolves instance.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed the other developers had a reason for repopulating the values after calling Resolve, but perhaps they did this due to an unfamiliarity with the framework. I tried this out and the populated values were what I expected to see.

Comment: Question, will this work for different users? This object might have different values for each logged-in user. Will it get back objects per-session or is this an application wide thing?

Comment: I was a bit premature. This creates a new instance of the object. I want the object the way it was first initialized, and I want to be able to do this for every user online, since the object will have different values depending on the current user. The object is being registered with RegisterType. Anything I can do?

Comment: You could probably create a child container per user and register user specific types with the child container.  Child containers will query the parent container if they don't have the required instances. Check out http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/UnityNestedContainersIUnityParentContainerCreateChildContainer.aspx